# Compiling C and assembly to pure machine code?

Tags: c, assembly, binary

I am really stuck right now...

Bootable files like the vmlinuz binary file, the MBR and the BOOTMGR image are all written in pure binary/machine code. But they have been compiled from C and assembly - i.e the linux kernel source isn't made up of just 1's and 0's, its made up of C source. How would i take my assembly and C programs and compile them to machine code for the general x86 (in my case x86-32) microprocessor range so that i can boot from these files.

Answer (score 6):

There is a great resource for this kind of thing: [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org).

Look in particular at the [Bare bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) page: it walks you through the process of creating, building and running a minimalist "kernel" written in assembly and C.

Also look at the [Baby steps](http://wiki.osdev.org/Babystep1) pages for how to build a boot sector.